# read specific websourcecode in c#

Tags: c#, http

When I press a button the following happens:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
                                  .Create("http://oldschool.runescape.com/slu");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

In short the data gets transferred to my textbox (this works perfectly)

Now if I choose world 78 (for example, from a combobox, it will refer to the last digits of that line) I want to get the value 968, if i choose world 14, I want to get the value 973.

This is an example of the printed data

```
e(378,true,0,"oldschool78",968,"United States","US","Old School 78");
e(314,true,0,"oldschool14",973,"United States","US","Old School 14");
```

What can I use to read this?

Answer (score 1):

So there are two problems here, the first is selecting the right line, then getting the number out.

First you want a method for getting each of the lines in to a list, eg using something like this:

```
List<String> lines = new List<String>()
string line = sr.ReadLine();
while(line != null)
{
     lines.Add(line);
     line = sr.ReadLine(); // read the next line
}
```

Then you need to find the relevant line and get the token out of it.

Probably the most simple way is, for each line, split the string up by ',', '\"', '(' and ')' (using 
[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a)). Ie, we get basically the parameters.

Eg

```
foreach(string lineInFile in lines)
{
     // split the string in to tokens
     string[] tokens = lineInFile.Split(',', '\"', '(', ')');
     // based on the sample strings and how we've split this, 
     // we take the 15th entry 
     string endParameter = tokens[15]; //endParamter = "Old School 14"
     ...
```

We now use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to extract the number. The pattern we will use is d+, ie 1 or more digits.

```
     Regex numberFinder = new Regex("\\d+");
     Match numberMatch = numberFinder.Match(endParameter);

     // we assume that there is a match, because if there isn't the string isn't
     // correct, you should do some error handling here

     string matchedNumber = numberMatch.Value;
     int value = Int32.Parse(matchedValue); // we convert the string in to the number
     if(value == desiredValue)
     ...
```

We check if the value matches the value we were looking for (eg 14), we now need to get the number you wanted.

We've already split the parameters, and the number we want is the 8th item (eg index 7 in string[] tokens). Since, at least in your example, this is just a lone number, we can just parse this to get the int.

```
     {
          return Int32.Parse(tokens[7]);
     }
}
```

Again here we are assuming that the string is in the formats you showed, and you should do error protection here to.

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I needed. I can't thank you enough for this!

Comment: Do I need to put the first codeblock into a lus? I can't figure out how it is supposed to add each line to the list without using any indexnumbers or statements.

For examample: for(int i = 0; i < /* the length of sr; i++){lines[i] = /* line number "i";

Comment: Not sure was a 'lus' is :P but I missed out reading the next line, which meant it would have just infinitely added the first line! I've fixed this in the above code.

Another thing to be careful of, in your code, you've actually already read the whole document. Instead, I would do my method of extracting line by line first, then you can use that list to add to the text box if still required.

Comment: Thanks ! By a lus I meant a loop, wrote it down in my own language :/ And many thanks again :D